# when submit jquery form dynamic change action url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery ajax form library.... i want to change action url  when i submit form

html

```
 <div class="modal-body form"><?php echo form_open_multipart("#",array('id'=>'mng_form', 'name'=>'mng_form','class'=>'form-horizontal','role'=>'form')); ?>
```

javascript

```
var options = {replaceTarget:true, beforeSubmit:  showRequest, success: showResponse};
```

how can i change action url using jquery form ?

Comment: where have you mentioned your action url?

Comment: use `$("#mng_form").attr("action", action);`

Comment: Can you give us a better example of your code? You could use the snippet tool in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery submit(). This happens prior to the actual submission, so you can change the action url.

```
<form id="fromID" action="action_page01.php" method="post" target="_blank" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

// jQuery
$( "#fromID" ).submit(function( event ) {
  $('#fromID').attr('action', 'action_page02.php');
});
```

Comment: Dimpal you are not making any sense to me. above is the code to change action url by jquery, now if you want to add triggers or bind the code to a button that will be a different matter. change the code to trigger on button click rather than submit button click.